# Dragula source model not defined

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I am using dragula with Angular for drag and drop. And it worked perfectly fine so far.

I have a data structure which has sections and every section has fields.

I have 2 source bags - one to drag and drop sections and I have one with fields which I can drop into sections. So it looks like :

```
data: { sections: [ { fields: []}]}
```

No problem so far - but now I wanted to extent the model and add a header to each section which can also receive fields:

data: { sections:[ { fields:[], headerfields: []}]}

My template looks like this:

```
 // Source bag

<div id="bag-source-fields" [dragula]='"bag-fields"' [dragulaModel]="fields">
   <div *ngFor="let field of fields">{{field.label}}</div>
 </div>

// Target bag

<div [dragula]='"bagfields"'[dragulaModel]="data.sections[i].fields">
   <div *ngFor="let field of section.fields;">
   .....
   ....
   </div>
```

And I added now my new bag:

```
<div [dragula]= '"bag=fields"' [dragulaModel] = "data.sections[i].headerfields">
    <div *ngFor="let field of data.sections[i].headerfields;">
    ...
    ...
    </div>
 </div>
```

But this breaks my system - I can drag the fields and the target container also reacts but as soon as I want to drop the field I get the error:

"sourceModel is undefined"

Any idea?

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: did you solve the problem?